# Sample Contacts on Android Emulator for Testing?

Tags: android-emulator, contacts, sample-data

Short of a) using a real device, or b) exporting/importing contacts via SD card ... then creating the SD card 'file' for the emulator, and importing it after each emulator launch ... is there a more turnkey (saner) way to get a set of sample contacts onto the emulator for test purposes?

Answer (score 6):

Easier than I thought! Whew.

When creating your Android Virtual Device (AVD), be sure to create a SD card of nominal size. (I used 20MB, which is plenty big for my purposes.) That's it in a nutshell.

Start the AVD, launch Contacts, tap Menu and create a few. When you close the AVD and launch next time, the contacts are still visible. Same thing goes for email accounts.